# How to understand this 2D dynamic array implementation? Is this the most basic implementation?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to C++ and am having trouble understanding this code. I put my current understanding in the comments. Is this the correct way of thinking about this? If not, what is being done? (in simple terms)

```
int** arrayA;  //a pointer to a pointer
arrayA = new int* [2]; //Does this 2 mean that there will be 2 rows?

arrayA[0] = new int[3]; //for the first row, three columns
arrayA[1] = new int[3]; //for the second row, three columns

/*Are the two lines above this CREATING or just ACCESSING the array? */
```

If my array had 3 rows, would I have to add `arrayA[2] = new int[3];`?

I know that I also have to delete it since it is dynamically allocated, or else there will be a memory leak error in the heap. Correct?

Comment: It means 2 rows and 3 columns. They will be accessed as `arrayA[row_number][column_number]`

Comment: `//2 pointers`: Wrong. Only one pointer.

Comment: @NickyC Oh I thought each * meant a pointer. So what does a ** mean?

Comment: @Jaden, it means a pointer to pointers.

Comment: What you have is called a **jagged array**, with manual memory management. Instead use [a single `std:.vector` as storage](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays/10246/a-dynamic-size-matrix-using-stdvector-for-storage#t=20161011034250957132) for the array.

Comment: @Jaden, your understanding is accurate. There is not much else to say in an answer.

Comment: @user4581301 but then is it still dynamically allocated?

Comment: Gooned code. Deleted comment. Gist was why dynamically allocate if you know the dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a traditional 2d array.  This is an array of pointers to arrays.  The memory is not guaranteed to be contiguous.  However, it has the nice property of allowing you to say:

```
my_pseudo_2d_array[1][3]
```

when it is passed in to a function as a double pointer - whereas an actual 2d array passed in as a pointer would require doing `row* width + column` math for accessing an element.

Comment: isn't this just the basic implementation of a static array? Correct me in I'm wrong

Comment: A static array is a contiguous array of elements and is minimally sized.  This has an additional memory overhead of one pointer per row.  a 2d array of ints has size width * height * sizeof(int).  This has size width * height * sizeof(int) + height * sizeof(pointer)  Also, you array requires manual cleanup (delete[] in a for loop followed by another delete[]) whereas a static array is lexically scoped.

Comment: That math mentioned in your last sentence is not required - you seem to be describing the situation of aliasing a 2-d array as a 1-d array

Comment: @M.M it's required if you pass it in to a function and don't have the exact dimensions available while writing the function.  (MyType * array, int width, int height) is a pretty common idiom, no?

Comment: So `int randomarray[2][0]` would be a static array with two rows and 3 columns, and `anotherarray[1][3]` is a dynamically allocated array with 1 row and 3 columns? I feel as if I would get an error if I tried this

Comment: No.   int some_array[X][X1][X2]....[Xn] is statically allocated.   Its dimensions are only known to the compiler - there is no inherent structure to the memory.  It's just a long string of bytes.   When you allocate it like you did, there is an inherent structure to the data, as you can dereference from your first array to get a discrete set of bytes representing the *second D* of your array.   If it were a 3d array, this sequence of dereferencing to get to the *next D* could be repeated.  However, I'm afraid I'm just confusing you.   The short version is, your dynamic array is more...

Comment: convenient for passing to functions, but less memory efficient, more complicated to allocate, and requires manual cleanup.